# scrollHeight in IE7 returns incorrect value unless specifically referenced before used

Tags: javascript, css

I have been working on an Accordion class for MooTools that is more catered to what I need, but have noticed that in IE7 (which I still need to support), element.scrollHeight returns an incorrect value unless I specifically reference it before using it. For example, I have an element with the classes "container" and "collapsed" & following styles that is hidden from the page:

```
.container {
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* removed when made visible */
.collapsed {
    left: -9999em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
}
```

When I need to display this element, I remove the class, and calculate its scrollHeight. In most browsers, this works fine. However, in IE7, the following code returns a height that is significantly smaller than the element's actual scrollHeight:

```
// remove the collapsed class
elem.removeClass('collapsed');

alert(elem.scrollHeight); // consistently '69px' across all accordion folds
```

However, if I reference elem.scrollHeight first, the alerted scrollHeight is correct:

```
// remove the collapsed class
elem.removeClass('collapsed');

if (elem.scrollHeight) alert(elem.scrollHeight); // the scrollHeight is correct
```

Does IE7 just need the additional few milliseconds to properly recalculate the element's scrollHeight, or is there something else at play?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

[See this table.](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html)

> When the element has no scrollbars IE makes the scrollHeight
>   equal to the actual height of the content; and not the height of the
>   element. scrollWidth is correct, except in IE8, where it’s 5 pixels
>   off.

And scrollHeight marked as 'incorrect' for ie5-7.
Maybe it will work with offsetHeight? Or calculate it somehow from other properties?

Also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930752/is-scrollheight-of-textarea-in-msie8-and-ff-differ) mentioned that...

> Whatever you do, in IE access the propertys not before body's onload
>   has fired, otherwise you will get weird results.