# textarea in FF and chrome to display with same size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, textarea

I have this textarea which I am doing a auto-resize, and for that I am using the scrollHeight property. FF looks very different from Chrome even when the page is just loaded and the field is empty. I have looked at a few suggestions (like [stackoverflowlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930752/is-scrollheight-of-textarea-in-msie8-and-ff-differ)), but I am not sure how to get them to look the same

This is the code that takes care of resizing:

```
 $('#idTextArea').each(function () {
        this.setAttribute('style', 'overflow-y:hidden;width:600px;');
        this.style.height = 'auto';
        this.style.height = (this.scrollHeight) + 'px';
        console.log("this.scrollHeight",this.scrollHeight);

      }).on('input', function () {
        this.style.height = 'auto';
        this.style.height = (this.scrollHeight) + 'px';
});
```

and this is the field:

```
<textarea id="idTextArea" 
      name="textName"
      maxlength="200"
      style="width: 600px;"><%=controller.getText("textName") == null? "":controller.getText("textName")%></textarea>
```

when my page loads, console.log prints 26 on Chorme and 49 on FF. 
So my question is: How to I get them to look the same?

Comment: `'px;overflow-y:hidden;width:600px;'` - what is px supposed to be in that style??

Comment: well the color coding shows an error

Comment: @JaromandaX, sorry that was just a typo. i removed it

Comment: @epascarello is was also a problem when i was copying the code and editing here to make it look nicer. thanks for noticing

Comment: What is different exactly? Are using a css reset lib to normalize the CSS between browsers?

Comment: scrollheight is different. I want them to have the same height. But FF is much taller (49 compared to 26 from Chrome)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try to add:`box-sizing: content-box;` to your textarea.

Comment: it didn't help.. :(